# How do i hide script Cam?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scriptcam

i have initialized script cam and now i want to hide it with javascript on the go and enable it back. setting the visibility of the div to hidden or display to none doesn't help. making the div hide using jquery makes the scriptcam not to work. please help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#getUserInfo').hide();
            $("#webcam").scriptcam({
                fileReady: fileReady,
                cornerRadius: 0,
                cornerColor: 'e3e5e2',
                onError: onError,
                promptWillShow: promptWillShow,
                showMicrophoneErrors: false,
                showDebug: true,
                onWebcamReady: onWebcamReady,
                setVolume: setVolume,
                timeLeft: timeLeft,
                fileName: 'demo982102',
                connected: showRecord,
                maximumTime: 15,
                width: 600,
                height: 450
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's detach().
http://api.jquery.com/detach/

It will remove the div from the DOM. When you want it back, use appendTo().

```
$("#webcam").detach();
```

Comment: it hides the player , but it makes it stop working . I wont get the call backScript called back :'(

Comment: You can also try setting the z-index to really low to hide it under the current page.                        `$("#webcam").css('z-index', -3000);`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by setting the width to 0 of the div which the player is in :D